# Will CSS <link /> tag block HTML parsing in various browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

As for various browsers, during the normal process of HTML parsing flow, will e.g **`<link href="xxx.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`** 
**block the rest of HTML parsing**?

It is commonly known that the script tag (e.g **`<script src="xxx.js"></script>`** )does block the HTML rendering

Comment: what Happened when you tested this?

Comment: I'm recently engaged in optimizing a big site where couple of <link /> are appended before the </body> tag which I saw has impacts on the speed of HTML parsing but with no confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, you wonder if the links in your header :  and  are stoping your page from loading ?
If the content from those links is fund, they will be loaded and the page will continue to load until the end of the script. However, if for some reasons the content from the links can't be fetch, then the browser will stop loading and wait for the content to be available.
There is a timeout after which the browser gives up and try to render the page without the linked content.
It usually results in Brocken UI and/or page functions run by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rendering the page will be delayed when you point to external stylesheets that way. Thats also often wished to not show a version of the page without style to the user.

In contrast to JavaScript references which are often set to the bottom of the page because of multiple reasons (download time + execution time + need for DOM elements to manipulate), CSS after loading should not take that much time to be applied.

However, despite HTTP/2 could increase the download time by parallel request for you, tools like [loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS), which provide asynchronous loading of CSS might help decrease blocking of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Our CSS must load fully before our HTML for various reasons.

Let me give you one such possible reason *(And this question was asked to me in an interview)*

Consider the scenario where we have to show a particular HTML element (e.g `button` element in my example) only after hovering on some other HTML element(say a `span` element in my example).
So as the HTML loads into the Browser our button element should  have `display:none;` and it should not been rendered initially. Only when the user *hovers* on the *span* element the `button` element will be shown.

In the code snippet I have implemented the scenario. And it is working as per the requirement.

Now if CSS was non-blocking instead  of blocking, then we could image that `Button` element would have behaved weirdly. Sometimes it will show up initially then, disappear all of a sudden.

So for all such scenarios it is best for CSS to be Blocking only - so that we allow CSS to load first and then the HTML, which will make sure that all the *html elements* have their respective proper CSS styling being applied no matter what.

```css
.box{
  display:block;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  padding:2rem;
}

button{
  display:none;
}

.box span{
 cursor:pointer;
}

.box span:hover ~ button{
  display:block;
}

.box span:hover{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
      <span> Hover over me to see the secret Button</span>
      <button>I am  the Secret Button</button>
  </div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

*Hope this answer is helpful to new developers and other :)*